# Wrting info to file using InstallJammer Installer s/w

Tags: installation

guys,
I am using InstallJammer , a tool for creating the installation file for product.
I have requirement that accept the one value say ,IPAddress, and write this address into the one file .
Anyone know how to do this [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/)

or How to do this in any other installtion s/w  ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallJammer has a Write Text to File action that will do just what you need.  The docs should tell you everything you need to know about how to use the action.

Answer (score 1):

under

> Install User InterFace > Install Panes
>   and Action

go to your screen insert action `Console Get User Input` and save it in virtual string like `<%myip%>` then insert action `Write Text to File` and under `Text to Write` write

```
<%myip%>
```